# Weighting the inverse of the variance in linear mixed model

Tags: r

I have a linear mixed model which is run 50 different times in a loop.

Each time the model is run, I want the response variable b to be weighted inversely with the variance. So if the variance of b is small, I want the weighting to be bigger and vice versa. This is a simplified version of the model:

```
model <- lme(b ~ type, random = ~1|replicate,weights = ~ I(1/b))
```

Here's the R data files:

b: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ziipdtsih5f0252/b.Rdata?dl=0

type: https://www.dropbox.com/s/90682ewib1lw06e/type.Rdata?dl=0

replicate: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kvrtao5i2g4v3ik/replicate.Rdata?dl=0

I'm trying to do this using the weights option in lme. Right now I have this as:

```
 weights = ~ I(1/b).
```

But I don't think this is correct....maybe weights = ~ I(1/var(b)) ??

I also want to adjust this slightly as b consists of two types of data specified in the factor variable (of 2 levels) type.

I want to inversely weight the variance of each of these two levels separately. How could I do this?

Comment: I think it's not correct as stated. Without a data example, this will be difficult to address. You say that you are weighting by the inverse of the variance, but then you are supply an expression that is the inverse of what appears to be a variable value itself. And then you use some sort of dot-operator to imply grouping operations???

Comment: Sorry! I've now edited my post so it's a bit clearer and included my data files

Comment: Any ideas for how to inversely weight the variance of the two levels of data in my response variable, separately?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it makes sense to talk about weighting the *response* variable in this manner. The descriptions I have found in the R-SIG-mixed-models mailing list refer to using inverse weighting derived from the predictor variables, either the fixed effects or the random effects. The weighting is used in minimizing the deviations of approximation of the model fits to the response. There is a function that returns the fixed effects variance (a sub-class of the `varFunc` family of functions) and it has a help page (linked from the weights section of the `?gls` page):

```
?varFixed
?varFunc
```

It requires a formula object as its argument. So my original guess was:

```
model <- lme(b ~ type, random = ~1|replicate, weights = varFixed( ~type) )
```

Which you proved incorrect. How about seeing if this works:

```
model <- lme(b ~ type, random = ~1|replicate, weights = varFixed( ~1| type) )
```

(My continuing guess is that this weighting is the default situation and specifying these particular weights may not be needed. The inverse nature of the weighting is implied and does not need to be explicitly stated with "1/type". In the case of mixed models the "correct" construction depends on the design and the prior science and none of this has been presented, so this is really only a syntactic comment and not an endorsement of this model. I did not download the files. Seems rather odd to have three separate files and no code for linking them into a dataframe. Generally one would want to have a single data object within which the column names would be used in the formulas of the regression function. (I also suspect this is the default behavior of this function and so my untested prediction is that that you would be getting no change by omitting that 'weights' parameter.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I had read the help page before but it's not always easy to decipher. I've now combined the variables into a data frame.

However I do get an error when I tried to apply the weights function - "Error in Math.factor(attr(object, "covariate")) :    abs not meaningful for factors." 

So I'm not sure I should be applying the inverse weighting to type?

Comment: I wanted to apply the variance structure to a factor and got the same error message as @user2846211. Instead of using varFixed, try using varIdent, e.g., `varIdent(form = ~ 1 | type)`. This is summarized in page 76 of Zuur et al 2009, *Mixed effects models and extensions in ecology with R*.

Comment: Here's an easily accessible (Which most of Zuur's work is not)  citation that supports @Nova's suggestion: https://idaejin.github.io/bcam-courses/neiker-2016/material/mixed-models/#heteroskedasticity